# selecting items in a list with key presses

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create "lanes" in a game. So far what I've done is made a list of pixel amounts for elements to line up at.

```
lanes = [HEIGHT - 300, HEIGHT - 240, HEIGHT - 180, HEIGHT - 120, HEIGHT - 60]
```

I have a player I want to move from lane to lane base on if the user hits up or down on the keyboard.

```
keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
        # I'm not sure what to do right here...
        self.rect.y -= lanes

    if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        # I'm not sure what to do right here...
        self.rect.y += lanes
```

How can I effectively cycle through the list items incrementally based on input? If there is a better way to do this, I am all ears. I'm a python beginner.

EDIT: Including a link to the full code in case there are details I am forgetting are important: http://pastebin.com/guAJMXzP

Comment: Why are you using `pygame.key.get_pressed()` instead of the event queue?

Comment: @ppperry To be honest, I don't know. I've followed a tutorial to get to this point and so far it has worked.

Comment: What tutorial are you following?

Comment: It's a video series I've followed and adapted the code to make another game. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLsk-HSGFjnaH5yghzu7PcOzm9NhsW0Urw

Answer (score 0):

You may want to keep separate track of which lane they're currently in and just set the location based on that. For example, if they start in the first lane, you might initialize `self.lane = 0`. Then, to keep the lane number in the proper range with a lookup of the actual y position at the end, your update might look like the following:

```
if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
    self.lane = max(0, self.lane-1)

if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    self.lane = min(self.lane+1, len(lanes)-1)

self.rect.y = lanes[self.lane]
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, now when up or down is pressed the character skips from the top of the move-able area to the bottom and so on.

Comment: Might want to try adding some debugging print statements on the update (e.g.,, add a `print self.lane` after each of the `self.lane =` assignments). If your game loop is running very quickly, it may just be moving from 0 to 1 to 2 etc. too quickly for you to see the intermediate steps.

Comment: I've done this and it seems the player continues to move through the entire list. I just want it to move to the next item in the list whether it is up or down. I'll include the full code in the post to clarify any details.